# Why is css margin-bottom not effecting the rest of the boxes?

Tags: html, css

it affects only the first as one seen in this picture.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="srow">
   <div class="sdw" style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">
     <img style="height:150px; border-radius:5px;" src="img/placeholder.png"> <br>
     <div style="margin-top:-157px">Item title...</div> <br>
     <div style="margin-top:94px;">Price</div>
   </div>
   <div class="sdw" style="float:right;margin-right:5px;">
     <img style="height:150px; border-radius:5px;" src="img/placeholder.png"> <br>
     <div style="margin-top:-157px">Item title...</div> <br>
     <div style="margin-top:94px;">Price</div>
   </div>
```

Css:

```
.srow{
   margin-bottom: 160px;
 } 
.sdw{
  height:150px;width:150px;
}
```

Comment: show more of your code and CSS. In these lines there is no problem.

Comment: ``margin-top -157px``..., no relevant html, sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's separate your CSS from your HTML in my own example:

```
#wrap {
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.image {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.image h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
.image h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Now, let's write some HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <h2>Price</h2>
</div>
```

We'll make four boxes and wrap them all together:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
         <h1>Title</h1>    
         <h2>Price</h2>    
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
         <h1>Title</h1>    
         <h2>Price</h2>    
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
         <h1>Title</h1>    
         <h2>Price</h2>    
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
         <h1>Title</h1>    
         <h2>Price</h2>    
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle of this example!](http://jsfiddle.net/LYVkD/)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your `div` are all floated. The `div` has no height, and the next elements get wherever they fit next.

You may want to add something with a `clear: both` at the end of your `div`.

Or avoid `float`.